# Json Ajax Calls - The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: c#, json, wcf, iis, cordova

We have a PhoneGap APP running on iOS and Android, which is calling WCF Webservices (hosted on IIS7 in development) and also on Azure (when in Production).  The WCF calls are made using json Ajax requests. Phonegap is using "FileTransfer"

When we upload large images, the App sends the image, but the WebService never recieves it.  Small images work fine.

The message in the WebService log files is:

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

We've searched and searched and we've increased the maxSize on almost everything we can lay our hands on in the WebService web.config file - but to no avail.

Any help on this would be VERY much appreciated.

Comment: Fixed! This worked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343628/wcf-maxreceivedmessagesize-not-being-read-from-config